# InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet;

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

On the spring data I do PageCommon but I get exception

myrestcontroller:

```
@Secured({"EMAKET_DEVELOPER", "EMAKET_BACK"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/getExceptionListLogs", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity getDocList(@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false) Integer start,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "count", required = false) Integer count,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "rn") String rn) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(otherImpl.getExceptionListLogs(start, count, rn));
}
```

service

```
@Override
public PageCommon getExceptionListLogs(Integer start, Integer count, String rn) {
    if (start == null || start == 0 || count == null || count == 0) {
        start = DEF_START_ZERO;
        count = DEF_CNT_DECLAR;
    }
    PageRequest request = PageRequest.of(start, count, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
    Page<ExcControlLog> exc = excControlLogRepository.findAll(request);
    return wrapPageToPageCommon(exc);
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ExcControlLogRepository extends JpaRepository<ExcControlLog, String> {
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXC_CONTROL_LOG", schema = "em5")
public class ExcControlLog implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private BigDecimal id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "SICID", referencedColumnName = "SICID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, targetEntity = Person.class)
    private Person person;
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "DAT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dat;
    @Column(name = "BRID")
    private String brid;
    @Column(name = "USR")
    private String user;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EXC", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private ExcControl excControl;
    @Column(name = "IP")
    private String ip;
}
```

stack

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:986)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

EXC_CONTROL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXC_CONTROL", schema = "em5")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "ExcControl.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM ExcControl m"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "ExcControl.findByOsn11", query = "SELECT m FROM ExcControl m WHERE m.osn.id = 11"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "ExcControl.findByOsnNull", query = "SELECT m FROM ExcControl m WHERE m.osn is null ")
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class ExcControl implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private BigDecimal id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "SICID", referencedColumnName = "SICID")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
    private Person person;
    @Column(name = "DAT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dat;
    @JoinColumn(name = "OSN", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, targetEntity = ZOsn.class)
    private ZOsn osn;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "excControl")
    private ExcControlLog excControl;

    public ExcControl() {
    }
}
```

Person

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Getter
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SICID")
    private BigDecimal sicid;
    @Column(name = "ACTID")
    private long actid;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "MIDDLENAME")
    private String middlename;

    public Person() {
    }
}
```

Comment: please also add the entity classes ExcControl and Person

Comment: can you also share the schemas of the tables